# Openimaj capture and save video from integrated camera or usb camera to hardisk (java)

Tags: openimaj

I just installed almost all libraries of openimaj instruction wise from the site: http://sourceforge.net/p/openimaj/wiki/OpenIMAJ%20From%20Source/ libraries are installed and working. I just need a sample code to capture video from webcam and save it to hard disk. For example:

This is the code to turn on the camera and show you video:

---

```
import org.openimaj.image.MBFImage;
import org.openimaj.video.VideoDisplay;
import org.openimaj.video.VideoDisplayListener;
import org.openimaj.video.capture.VideoCapture;

public class VideoDemo {
    ...
    VideoCapture vc = new VideoCapture( 320, 240 );
    VideoDisplay<MBFImage> vd = VideoDisplay.createVideoDisplay( vc );
    ...
}
```

---

How do I save [vd] on disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [XuggleVideoWriter](http://www.openimaj.org/apidocs/org/openimaj/video/xuggle/XuggleVideoWriter.html) class. The following code displays the video content on the screen and writes the content to a file until the escape key is pressed. The format of the video is controlled by the name of the file (i.e. "video.flv" creates an FLV format video).

```
package org.openimaj.demos.sandbox;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.openimaj.image.MBFImage;
import org.openimaj.video.Video;
import org.openimaj.video.VideoDisplay;
import org.openimaj.video.VideoDisplayListener;
import org.openimaj.video.capture.VideoCapture;
import org.openimaj.video.xuggle.XuggleVideoWriter;

/**
 * Record the webcam to a file.
 * 
 * @author Jonathon Hare (jsh2@ecs.soton.ac.uk)
 */
public class VideoRecorder extends KeyAdapter implements VideoDisplayListener<MBFImage> {
    private Video<MBFImage> video;
    private VideoDisplay<MBFImage> display;
    private XuggleVideoWriter writer;
    private boolean close = false;

    /**
     * Default constructor
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public VideoRecorder() throws IOException {
        //open webcam
        video = new VideoCapture(320, 240);

        //open display
        display = VideoDisplay.createVideoDisplay(video);

        //open a writer
        writer = new XuggleVideoWriter("video.flv", video.getWidth(), video.getHeight(), 30);

        //set this class to listen to video display events
        display.addVideoListener(this);

        //set this class to listen to keyboard events
        SwingUtilities.getRoot(display.getScreen()).addKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterUpdate(VideoDisplay<MBFImage> display) {
        //Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeUpdate(MBFImage frame) {
        //write a frame 
        if (!close) {
            writer.addFrame(frame);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key) {
        //wait for the escape key to be pressed
        close = key.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE;
    }

    /**
     * Main method
     * @param args ignored
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new VideoRecorder();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i add audio to this class?